# Ataques de SPAM con preguntas sin sentido en el sitio. Como actuar

Tags: discusión

Como muchos de ustedes notaron (o no), de alguna forma algún profesor en algún lado decidió dar de tarea a sus alumnos que publicaran una pregunta sin sentido en el sitio...

Aunque tenemos identificadas varias de las mismas (por ejemplo: Como programar una secuencia en python) algunas otras, pasan por preguntas reales, solo que mal hechas.

Pero mirando un poco al usuario, nos damos cuenta (y mas los moderadores diamantados que tenemos algunas herramientas mas) que solo se esta generando SPAM en el sitio.

Los moderadores hablamos este tema con los CM y el sitio decidió que no hay mucho que podamos hacer al respecto (por el momento) porque bloquear a todo un grupo de usuarios (donde podría haber usuarios reales) no estaría bien.

Por lo tanto los moderadores estamos eliminando las preguntas (la mayoría es cerrada antes que lleguemos) y estamos comunicándonos con los usuarios, alertándolos de la situación.

Como los votos de cierre son algo escasos, y en general llegamos a eliminarlas rápidamente (parece que actúan sobre los mismos horarios en los que estoy activo), se me ocurren varias ideas para evitar que gasten los votos de cierre.

- Podemos optar por generar una sala en el chat solo para postear las preguntas sospechosas (hay algunas respuestas que también lo son) y de esa forma los moderadores las encontramos mas rápido.
- Pueden reportarlas como spam, aunque esto es peligroso porque si la pregunta es real y tiene mucho reportes por spam, va a desaparecer sola...
- pueden reportarlas usando la opción otras (se necesita la intervención de un moderador), y aclarando que es posible spam.

Dejo a votación que método les parece mejor.

Lo que si, si algún usuario vota alguna de estas preguntas positivamente, invítenlos a leer esta publicación para que retire su voto.
No las voten negativas.. simplemente no les hagan caso.
No entren en debates ni en comentarios respecto a las publicaciones.

Si notamos que es solo una mala pregunta, de alguna forma dejaremos un comentario al usuario para que la mejore, de esa forma nos daremos cuenta que es un usuario real.

Comment: Me gusta la idea de la sala de chay,creo que es la alternativa más viable y correcta, ya que asjsepuede orientar a otros usuarios a como actuar ante estas publicaciones

Comment: Ya me parecían raras esas preguntas mal formuladas con votos positivos :0, si creo que la sala de chat estaría bien.

Comment: La tercera opción parece la más rápida y limpia. En una sala de chat, al final no sé si se acabarán reportando multiples veces la misma pregunta, haciendo perder el tiempo a moderador y usuarios. Sin embargo, mi conocimiento de como funciona el sitio aún es limitado. Cualquier cosa que se haga para evitar esas preguntas molestas me parece bien.

Comment: Pues sí, yo me había dado cuenta, sí. Acaba de aparecer una justo mientras leía esto. Lamentable.

Comment: La tercera opción, la de "Otras" ¿Dónde aparece? No encuentro el camino exacto al ir marcando los radio buttons.

Comment: @RubioRic donde dice se necesita la intervencion de un moderador.. ahi lo aclaro!!!

Comment: Me acabo de encontrar una pregunta con dos respuestas prácticamente iguales con una hora de diferencia (una dice hace 21 horas y la otra hace 22 horas) de usuarios nuevos que claramente no entendieron la pregunta. Se trata de cómo descargar un archivo usando código pero en lugar de indicar código o dar orientación al respecto indican los pasos para hacer la descarga manual. Me llama la atención que esto coincida con lo de las preguntas spam.

Comment: @Rubén marcamelas... ya detecto el spam al voleo....

Comment: @gbianchi Hecho!

Comment: @gbianchi Hombre, ahí lo aclaras despues de editar!!! Gracias!!!! Has oido lo de Terry Pratchett y las exclamaciones? Perdón, no puedo evitarlo. ;-P

Comment: De qué preguntas hablan? Se oye interesante. Tal vez alguien, o varios, conocidos del sitio puedan agrupar el tema de lo que se trata, ligarlas a una respuesta específica, y luego cerrarlas. Quizás luego se puedan publicar en una sala de chat o aquí, y luego votamos para cerrarlas y relacionarlas con las publicaciones relativas al problema espefíco. ¿Si me pude dar a entender?

Comment: @Cuauhtli como? no entiendo que estas diciendo.. las preguntas se borran directamente...

Comment: Olvidalo. Estaba complicando las cosas. Tienes razón. De todas maneras, ¿Tienen un ejemplo de esas preguntas que dicen? Me gustaría leer las publicaciones de los alumnos de ese profesor.

Comment: @Cuauhtli se eliminan directamente.. si ves alguna te vas a dar cuenta...

Comment: [este caso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499589/como-puedo-hacer-este-array-en-javascript) tendŕia que estar en un museo, no se si es específicamente lo que comentas, pero claramete hay que hacer algo. Tanto las preguntas como las respuestas son una completa confusión. De los 3 usuarios que participan, 2 crearon la cuenta ese mismo día.

Comment: @Emeeus nop.. es solo una mala pregunta con respuestas peores...

Comment: yo vería mejor a parte de la sala crear un robot que examine los enlaces y los sospechosos lo envié a colas de revisión o moderadores directamente o ambos

Answer (score 6):

Aunque en lo personal procuro usar poco las salas de chat considero que una sala de chat **de propósito específico** para atender situaciones emergentes como esta, incluyendo el que ya ha sido revisada con los CM y no se puede hacer algo drástico como se ha explicado, debería ser algo que se implemente inmediatamente.

Al revisar los casos sospechosos, ver como reaccionan los usuarios que están publicando esas preguntas y la comunidad se tendrían mejores bases para determinar cuales de las opciones se podrían implementar y mantener de "6 a 8 semanas".

Comment: Si desean crear una sala de chat para ese tipo de casos deberian revisar la experiencia de la sala https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers de SOen, alli existe un conjunto de herramientas que nos permiten manejar esos casos como por ejemplo etiquetas especiales segun el problema, userscripts, bots que rastrean tráfico inusual, etc.

Comment: gracias @eyllanesc.. tenemos smokedetector activado en la sala internacional y tratamos de detectar estos casos, pero no siguen un patron... no se que otras cosas usan ahi...

Comment: @gbianchi smokedetector no solo sirve para detectar casos, tambien puedes habilitarlos para seguir la acción de usuarios sospechosos por lo que si crean un nuevo post de ese tipo de usuarios podrian avisarte. Por otro lado mi comentario iba en que si van a crear una sala específica entonces no comiencen desde cero sino que pueden usar la experiencia existente en esa sala que como ya mencione son las reglas, los bots, los userscripts, etc. En esa sala (al menos yo) se siente que hay un trabajo colaborativo para limpiar el sitio, siento además que se evitan los conflictos de intereses, etc

Comment: por eso te agradeci el comentario @eyllanesc y te comente que usabamos smoke.. desgraciadamente, ya lo hable todo esto con los chicos de smoke... y el problema es que el "patron" es ambiguo...

Comment: Si alguno se anima a crear la sala les agradeceré que dejen un comentario o respuesta.

Comment: quien era el user 22539?

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent viendo las menciones de Gbianchi, parece que era eyllanesc