# ¿Podemos quitar los enlaces agregados en preguntas donde claramente busquen SEO?

Tags: discusión, ediciones

Desde que he tenido suficiente reputación para editar preguntas, que **he visto pasar algunas preguntas** donde claramente no eran preguntas en sí, sino que eran **usadas para hacer SEO**.

Dada mi experiencia previa en este tema, sé positivamente que cuando alguien consigue colocar un enlace en una web que no es suya, ya sea mediante comentarios u otros sistemas, **hay formas de conseguir que los buscadores vengan enseguida a esas webs a indexarlas, de forma masiva**, para así conseguir más reputación en la web enlazada. Cuando digo enseguida me refiero a pocos minutos, vamos, casi de forma immediata.

Son **trucos de SEO (o black SEO, como querais) ampliamente usados desde siempre**, que si bien les pueden durar poco porque sus trucos pueden ser detectados por los administradores de las webs y borrar esos comentarios o inserciones de enlaces, no por ello dejan de intentarlo continuamente, y aún borrando esos enlaces, ellos ya han conseguido su propósito, porque **una vez indexados pueden tardar un tiempo en desindexarse de nuevo**, pues ya depende de cada buscador y sus algoritmos de refresco de los datos almacenados.

Veo que eso tambien ocurre en SO en algunas preguntas, que como decia, he visto pasar en el poco tiempo que llevo activo y revisando, y quizás no tanto en respuestas, pero imagino que tambien alguna debe haber pasado historicamente.

Recientemente vi un caso flagante de eso, donde el OP, simulando una pregunta sin demasiado sentido, ponia dos veces un enlace a otro sitio, que además coincidia con su nombre de usuario. Para mi estuvo claro que **pretendia potenciar el SEO de su sitio ganando prestigio al conseguir tres enlaces y/o textos desde la misma página a su web**.

Como lo vi tan claro no me lo pensé dos veces y edité su contenido eliminando las urls que ponia, pues ademas no tenian ninguna repercusión en la comprensión de la supuesta pregunta, simplemente sobraban, no eran necesarios.

Esa pregunta tardó poco en cerrarse, quizás no llegó a los 30 minutos, pero desde mi punto de vista, y perdonad el rollo pero ya termino, **que una pregunta quede cerrada no evita que los buscadores accedan a ella**. Con lo cual deduzco que si no hubiera borrado esos enlaces el OP seguiria contento pues, a pesar de su cierre, podia seguir enviando los buscadores a reindexar la página.  Desconozco aún que ocurre con las preguntas cerradas, si finalmente alguien las elimina o se quedan así in eternum por si el OP quiere intentar reabrirlas.

Mi pregunta clave en esta exposición es: **¿Puedo eliminar los enlaces de una pregunta de este tipo, siempre que no afecte al significado de la pregunta, mientras hago revisiones o cuando la vea?** No es que pretenda salvar el planeta, simplemente me molesta ver como de vulnerable puede ser este sitio en este aspecto y supongo que también es mi *deje* profesional al respecto.

No tengo claro si me propasé haciendolo ese día con esta y no deberia haberlo hecho, o bien al hacerlo el resto de revisores/editores no lleguen a entender el porque se pide cerrarla y no voten por ello (aunque siempre pueden ir a las listas de  ediciones, pero intuyo que no muchos lo hacemos).

Comment: Esa pregunta... era puro spam... obviamente se creo no solo para darle SEO a esos links, si no tambien para generar trafico.
No he visto muchas preguntas de esas, de vez en cuando aparece alguna. Pero en esos casos, mejor avisar a los moderadores, asi podemos revisarla y ver que pasa. Igual, si logro su cometido, nos excede... se trabaja lo mas rapido que se puede...

Comment: Igual una pregunta cerrada sin respuestas se elimina automaticamente luego de un par de semanas.. y una pregunta reportada muchas veces como spam, se elimina automaticamente por el sistema luego de un par de minutos...

Comment: @gbianchi son borradas realmente o solo ocultas para quienes tienen menos de 10k?

Comment: son ocultadas.. un robot tampoco las puede ver... @Christian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Las "preguntas" que no son preguntas apropiadas para el sitio que descaradamente tienen finalidades de SEO deben ser reportadas como spam, no pierdas tiempo quitando los enlaces por un lado porque podrías estar dándoles más visibilidad, por ejemplo, los usuarios que sólo tienen el privilegio de sugerir ediciones, estarían mandando la pregunta a la cola de revisión de ediciones.

Cuando una pregunta o respuesta tienen suficientes reportes como spam se eliminan y se mandan a un listado especial con la finalidad de prevenir más publicaciones similares.

Recursos

- [reportar publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Relacionado

- [Ataques de SPAM con preguntas sin sentido en el sitio. Como actuar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5230/65)

Answer (score 0):

Aunque obviamente me molesta mucho, de todos modos no es mucho el beneficio que pueden obtener. Los links llevan `rel="nofollow noreferer"`

PD: Y no olviden comprar su ropa interior en [el palacio del calzoncillo](https://#). San Diego 287.

Comment: jeje, bueno, si bien ese atributo ayuda a no ser indexados en buscadores, no impide que herramientas de SEO sí que los tengan en cuenta y los valoren positivamente para calcular la reputación del dominio enlazado, y el número de enlaces, así como la reputación del sitio donde estan puestos, y SO tiene mucha reputación (lo se, hacen mal, pero la mayoria lo cuentan igual).